# Updating old code, what is Array(_unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 1024, initializingWith: 0)

Tags: arrays, swift

I have never run across this API before:

```
var a: [Number] = Array(_unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 1024, initializingWith: 0)
```

It seems like this is simply:

```
var a: [Number] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1024)
```

However, I've learned never to trust my gut feelings with Swift. Is anyone familiar with this API and can let me know if my conversion is doing the same thing?

Comment: Did you [see the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3200717-init)? I think that's the same one. But then again, the link shows it's new in Xcode 11.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz The linked function isn't quite the same, but regardless, I don't see your issue with that doc. I've never used that function, but it's perfectly clear to me what it does. Example usage would be nice, though.

Comment: Thoroughly explained here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0223-array-uninitialized-initializer.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost but not quite the same thing (although you're syntax seems wrong on the first).

First a brief description of how memory is allocated for arrays. Typically there's a pointer to the first element of the array, and then each value occupies consecutive memory slots. An array of size 4 with 4 memory slots allocated may occupy memory slots 100 -> 103 for example. If we were to add a 5th element, we'd have to change the pointer to a new starting memory slot with more capacity, then copy over all the elements on the original array, then add the new element. This can get inefficient if we keep overflowing the memory of the array (although modern phones can prob handle this with ease).

The first one, `Array(_unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:)` is an initializer that gives you access to the to the uninitialized memory slots as well. But basically it's saying to allocate enough memory for 1024 entries, and the `initializeWith` is an opportunity to fill some in as you are creating the array.

You might use it like this:

```swift
var myArray = Array<Int>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 10) { buffer, initializedCount in
    for x in 1..<5 {
        buffer[x] = x
    }
    buffer[0] = 10
    initializedCount = 5
}
```

which would return an array: `[10, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

The `buffer` gives you access to the WHOLE memory of the array (its `inout` so editing it in the closure directly changes it).
Then the `initializedCount` is another seemingly stored value that seems likes it's probably used to provide O(1) access to `array.count` and/or other stuff, docs require that value to equal the actual elements you filled in during the closure.

The second one, `Array(repeating: 0, count: 1024)` is also creating and filling the indices of the Array. I have no clue how memory allocation is chosen if unspecified but it stands to reason that if you don't specify how many slots you're planning on using, Apple adds some buffer room to not have to copy all those 1024 elements if we add another one so it might be equivalent to something like:

```
Array(_unsafeUninitializedCapacity: XXX, initializingWith: "0 for the first 1024 slots")
```

where XXX > 1024.

So while you may get an array with the same amount of 0's... in the nitty gritty memory world if you try to add a new element to the first one it will overflow and have to do this process of copying everything over.

The first one seems like something you would use if you were making a lot of edits appends, or changes to an existing array which might cause memory to overflow and as a result lots of copying.

In practice unless you're doing something... involved.. you could probably use something like: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1538966-reservecapacity if you want to optimize the memory AND THEN do all the array operations knowing you're not going to overflow.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, it is this sort of thing I feared. The issue is that initializingWith: has to be a closure, but I guess {0} is good enough for that?

Comment: edited, it should be better now.. interesting question still not sure why you would want to use the first really but interest..